# Zip all subdirectories using python

Tags: python, linux, unix, ubuntu

I am attempting to create a script that zips all of the subdirectories of a folder, then deletes the folders which have now been zipped

```
import shutil
import os
loc = "foldertzipfilesin"
path = "/whereparentis/" + loc + "/"
dirs = os.listdir( path )
for file in dirs:
   name =  file
   shutil.make_archive(name, 'zip', path)
   shutil.rmtree(name)
```

It seems to run, however it does not create the zip files.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your issue is with the path you're passing as an argument.

I've tried your script with the following changes:

```
import shutil
import os
loc = "testfolder"
path = os.getcwd() + '/' +  loc + "/"
dirs = os.listdir( path )
for file in dirs:
   name =  file
   shutil.make_archive(name, 'zip', path)
```

and it worked properly creating the zip files for every file in the loc folder. Files are created on the PATH where you've ran your script.